# Azure Storage Queue - correlate response to request

Tags: azure, queue, message-queue, azure-storage

When a Web Role places a message onto a Storage Queue, how can it poll for a specific, correlated response? I would like the back-end Worker Role to place a message onto a response queue, with the intent being that the caller would pick the response up and go from there.

Our intent is to leverage the Queue in order to offload some heavy processing onto the back-end Worker Roles in order to ensure high performance on the Web Roles. However, we do not wish to respond to the HTTP requests until the back-end Workers are finished and have responded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am actually in the middle of making a similar decision. In my case i have a WCF service running in a web role which should off-load calculations to worker-roles. When the result has been computed, the web role will return the answer to the client.

My basic data structure knowledge tells me that i should avoid using something that is designed as a queue in a non-queue way. That means a queue should always be serviced in a FIFO like manner. So basically if using queues for both requests and response,  the threads awaiting to return data to the client will have to wait untill the calculation message is at the "top" of the response queue, which is not optimal. If storing the responses by using Azure tables, the threads poll for messages creating unnecessary overhead

What i belive is a possible solution to this problem is using a queue for the requests. This enables use of the competeing consumers pattern and thereby load-balancing. On messages sent into this queue you set the [correlationId property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.brokeredmessage.correlationid.aspx) on the message. For reply the pub/sub part ("topics") part of Azure service bus is used togehter with a [correlation filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.correlationfilter.aspx). When your back-end has processed the request, it published a result to a "responseSubject" with the correlationId given in the original request. Now this response ca be retrieved by your client by calling CreateSubscribtion (Sorry, i can't post more than two links apparently, google it) using that correlation filter, and it should get notified when the answer is published. Notice that the CreateSubscribtion part should just be done one time in the OnStart method. Then you can do an async BeginRecieve on that subscribtion and the role will be notified in the given callback when a response for one of it's request is available. The correlationId will tell you which request the response is for. So your last challenge is giving this response back to the thread holding the client connection.

This could be achieved by creating Dictionary with the correlationId's (probably GUID's) as key and responses as value. When your web role gets a request it creates the guid, set it as correlationId, add it the hashset, fire the message to the queue and then call Monitor.Wait() on the Guid object. Then have the recieve method invoked by the topic subscribition add the response to the dictionary and then call Monitor.Notify() on that same guid object. This awakens your original request-thread and you can now return the answer to your client (Or something. Basically you just want your thread to sleep and not consume any ressources while waiting)

Answer (score 3):

The queues on the **Azure Service Bus** have a lot more capabilities and paradigms including **pub / sub** capabilities which can address issues dealing with queue servicing across multiple instance.

One approach with pub / sub, is to have one queue for requests and one for the responses. Each requesting instance would also subscribe to the response queue with a filter on the header such that it would only receive the responses targeted for it. The request message would, of course contain the value to the placed in the response header to drive the filter.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. I appreciate your response, and I will check out the Service Bus option. I noticed that your other answers were Azure-related. I hope to read many like them!

Comment: Thanks for the warm welcome. I hope to make more contributions. Yes, my current experience all azure related.

Answer (score 3):

For the Service Bus based solution there are samples available for implementing Request/Response pattern with [Queues](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/Brokered-Messaging-Request-0ce8fcaf) and [Topics (pub-sub)](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/Brokered-Messaging-Request-6759a36e)

Comment: Thank you. Does it have a facility for ensuring that, while the response is intended for the subscriber, the response is actually correlated with the original request?

Comment: In the same way as a simple Queue allows you to compete for Messages, a Session enabled Service Bus Queue allows you to compete for Sessions. Here you can specify a SessionId and then Lock that session. Any messages sent to that Session will only be delivered to you. Thus if each subscriber has their unique Id that they use as the SessionID and then send that along in the messages as ReplyToSessionId, the only code needed to guarantee the response is correlated is that for the Reply message we set: ReplyMessage.SessionId = RequestMessage.ReplyToSessionId.

This pattern is shown in the samples.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I voted you up. I chose the answer from [@Henrikmh](http://stackoverflow.com/users/859401/henrikmh) because of the last paragraph about using the Dictionary<Guid, Response> as the correlation mechanism. We will have many concurrent requests from the same host. The Session solves the subscription issue for the given host, but not for each concurrent request. I believe that you may have left that as an exercise for the reader. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Let worker role keep polling and processing the message. As soon as the message is processed  add an entry in Table storage with the required corelationId(RowKey)  and the processing result,  before deleting the processed message from the queue.

Then WebRoles just need to do a look up of the  Table with the desired correlationId(RowKey) & PartitionKey

Comment: Very cool idea. I like this fit, because only the Web Role that initiated the request needs to see the response. I will need some kind of garbage collector for orphaned Table Storage entries that never get popped in case of Web Role failures.

Comment: I don't think this is a good idea. Then you're basically building a new queue system (using table storage) instead of using the dedicate queue/topic features in Azure. Also you would have to poll the table storage for the response = very inefficient and not scalable.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at using [SignalR](https://github.com/SignalR) between the worker role and the browser client. So your web role puts a message on the queue and returns a result to the browser (something simple like 'waiting...') and hook it up to the worker role with SignalR. That way your web role carries on doing other stuff and doesn't have to wait for a result from asynchronous processing, only the browser needs to.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing intrinsic to Windows Azure queues that does what you are asking.  However, you could build this yourself fairly easily.  Include a message ID (GUID) in your push to the queue and when processing is complete, have the worker push a new message with that message ID into a response channel queue.  Your web app can poll this queue to determine when processing is completed for a given command.

We have done something similar and are looking to use something like SignalR to help reply back to the client when commands are completed.

Comment: This is what I was thinking. We are already including a Correlation Id GUID strategy, but it seems like a lot of polling on that response queue where the Web Role pulls irrelevant responses. When I call GetMessage() is there a way to quickly release it in the likely event that it is not the response I was waiting for? Or, alternatively, perhaps I could give each Web Role instance a dedicated queue. Even then, these queues are not FIFO, so I would still need to check that correlation id. Thoughts?

Comment: The catch with this is if you have more than one instance of the webrole (or even diff requests running on the same web role), there is a chance that the message intended for instance 1 will get picked up by instance 2, which will check the correlation id, realise it's not waiting for it and have to put it back on the queue.  I've tried this and it doesn't scale very well.  The table idea is much better.

Comment: Thanks for adding this comment. I was worried about that very thing, considering that IIS can process many requests simultaneously on the same box.

Comment: The reply queue would have to be 1:1 with your web front ends in this case.  You could have each webrole spin up and create it's own queue.  The table option is interesting, but if you don't know when a request will come, you end up querying a lot.  Popping a message means something you did has a response.

Comment: [@dunnry 1](http://stackoverflow.com/users/375911/dunnry): Even with 1:1 mapping, couldn't a web role have multiple requests running in parallel, that it handed off to the back end via the queue? If so, it still has to check the Correlation Id, because even though it has a dedicated queue, it cannot guarantee that the message it pulls from the queue is from a specific request otherwise.

Comment: I think you would be ok.  If webrole pops message it is because it came from client that was connected to it that instantiated initial request.  Using SignalR here to reply back on that channel would be sufficient.